# why my java program get terminated after printing "address" in the below code? is there is something with the read()and readline()method

Tags: java, file-io

please tell me the flow of this code I am not understanding what happening after the char s2=(char)br.read();

```
  import java.io.*;


  class demo 
  {

  public static void main(String[]arg) throws IOException

  {

InputStreamReader i=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
 BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(i);

 System.out.println("enter name");
 String s1=br.readLine();

 System.out.println("enter gender");
 char s2=(char)br.read();

 System.out.println("enter adress");
 String s3=br.readLine();

  System.out.println("name"+s1);
  System.out.println("gender"+s2);
  System.out.println("address"+s3);
  }
 }
```

Comment: the output of the above program is :- enter the name then enter gender then enter address and it is not fetching the value after the adress

Comment: In this context `readLine()` is used for reading next line input from user.

Comment: Please format your code for readability (indentations)

Comment: Now is the time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with your `br.read()`. Basically, you could have entered M and press enter. Then, this function call only pass `M` to gender, however, the new line character is still available in br, hence address will come as black. That is why program continues and completes successfully.

You can change from `br.read()` to `br.readLine()` for gender, and convert string to char accordingly (after validating input) to fix this problem.